# Visualizar ultimo registro de una tabla con foto

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Tengo una aplicación de registros dentales donde guardo la consulta del cliente y la foto del dentagrama usando `Entity Framework` de la siguiente forma:

```
                byte[] file = null;
            Stream mystream = opdImagen.OpenFile();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                mystream.CopyTo(ms);
                file = ms.ToArray();
            }
            using (Model.GRUDENTEntities db = new Model.GRUDENTEntities())
            {
                Model.Paciente oImage = new Model.Paciente();
                oImage.Documento = txtcedula.Text.Trim();
                oImage.Nombres = txtnombre.Text.Trim();
                oImage.PrimerApellido = txtpapellido.Text.Trim();
                oImage.SegundoApellido = txtsapellido.Text.Trim();
                oImage.Sexo = cmbsexo.Text.Trim();
                oImage.FechaDeNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpfechanacimiento.Value);
                oImage.EstadoCivil = cmbestadocivil.Text.Trim();
                oImage.GrupoSanguineo = cmbgruposanguineo.Text.Trim();
                oImage.ARS = cmbars.Text.Trim();
                oImage.NSS = txtnss.Text.Trim();
                oImage.CorreoElectronico = txtcorreoelectronico.Text.Trim();
                oImage.Telefono = txttelefono.Text.Trim();
                oImage.Celular = txtcelular.Text.Trim();
                oImage.Direccion = txtdireccion.Text.Trim();

                oImage.Foto = file;

                db.Paciente.Add(oImage);
                db.SaveChanges();
                LimpiarCampos();
                MessageBox.Show("Paciente registrado correctamente", "Operacion Exitosa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtnombre.Focus();
            }
```

en un datagridview de consulta puedo visualizar la foto de la manera siguiente:

```
DetalleConsulta fco = new DetalleConsulta();
            fco.lblnombre.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["NombrePaciente"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lbledad.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Edad"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lblsexo.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Sexo"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lblfecha.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Fecha"].Value.ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            fco.lbldoctor.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["NombreDoctor"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lblmotivo.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Motivo"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lblobservacion.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Observaciones"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lbldiagnostico.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Diagnostico"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lblprocedimiento.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Procedimiento"].Value.ToString();
            fco.lblindicacion.Text = dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["Indicaciones"].Value.ToString();


            if (dgvPacienteConsulta.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Ficha"].Selected)
            {

                int id = Convert.ToInt16(dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
                using (GRUDENTEntities db = new GRUDENTEntities())
                {

                    var oImage = db.Consulta.Find(id);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(oImage.Foto);
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);

                    fco.pbDentagrama.Image = bmp;
                    fco.Show();
                }
```

Lo que yo deseo es que me arroje la imagen en un picturebox de la última consulta del cliente en base al id del cliente que lo tengo en una variable llamada idd pero no tengo claro cómo. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Porque en esta linea `Model.Paciente oImage = new Model.Paciente();` defines la variable como `oImage` si lo que instancias es un paciente? deberia ser `Model.Paciente paciente = new Model.Paciente();`

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener una entidad por id usarias un filtro en entity framework

Algo como esto

```
int id = Convert.ToInt16(dgvPacienteConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
using (Model.GRUDENTEntities db = new Model.GRUDENTEntities())
{
    var paciente = db.Pacientes.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);
    if(paciente == null)
       return;

     fco.lblnombre.Text = paciente.Nombres;
     //resto propiedades

    using (MemoryStream ms= new MemoryStream(paciente.Foto))
    {
      fco.pbDentagrama.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

}
```

asi puede convertir el `byte[]` de la imagen para asignar al picturebox